# Passing variables to CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda, malloc

So, I am writing a PDE solver in **CUDA C++**. The solver is a function which in turn calls the cuda kernel to solve the PDE. Now, I want to use the PDE parameters as arguments to the kernel. That means I have to malloc for those variables like
`cudaMalloc((void **)&Nt_d,size);` and then `cudaMemcpy(&Nt_d,Nt,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);`(Nt is an integer) which is for pointers. I want to pass **integers** and as well as **floats**, i.e non-pointer variables but can't find the correct syntax for it. I don't want to use the parameters as global constants. I want to use them as arguments to the kernel. Is there any way to do so?
Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pass them directly; pass-by-value.

A kernel may have a prototype like this:

```
__global__ void mykernel(int *p1, float *p2, int i1, float f2);
```

in that case, `p1` and `p2` are pointer parameters, whereas `i1` is an `int` parameter passed by value, and `f2` is a `float` parameter passed by value.

This is more-or-less just a recital of what you would do for a function call in C or C++ for these types of parameters.  You can use those parameters like `i1` and `f2` in your kernel code directly, just as you would with an ordinary C/C++ function.

As you've already pointed out, pointer variables should presumably be pointing to allocations you've already set up on the device via e.g. `cudaMalloc`

You might want to study some CUDA [sample codes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#vector-addition), such as `vectorAdd`.